# Looking for example or documentation for wikidump python lib

Tags: python, mediawiki, wikipedia

I stumbled upon the [wikidump](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/wikidump) python library, which I think suits me just fine.

I could get by by looking at the source code, but I'm new at python and I don't want to write BS code as the project I need it for is kind of important to me.

I got the 'wiki-SPECIFICDATE-pages-articles.xml.bz2' file and I would need to use that as my source for single article fetching. Can anyone give me some pointers as to properly achieve this or, even better, point at some documentation? I couldn't find any!

(p.s. if you got any better and properly doc'd lib, please tell me)

Comment: Have you looked at their command-line client at https://github.com/saffsd/wikidump/blob/master/src/wikidump/__init__.py that can be used as an example?

Comment: I use http://medialab.di.unipi.it/wiki/Wikipedia_Extractor to convert Wikipedia to plain text. It can be modified easily to fetch any article. Just debug one article's processing and you will see where to insert a regex match for fetching.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understand the question, but if you have the Wikipedia dump and you need to parse the wikicode, I would suggest [mwparserfromhell](https://github.com/earwig/mwparserfromhell) lib.

Another powerful framework is [Pywikibot](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Pywikibot), that is the historic framework for bot users on Wikipedia (thus, it has many scripts dedicated to *writing* pages, instead of reading and parsing articles). It has a lot of documentation (though, sometimes obsolete) and it uses MediaWiki API.

You can use them both, of course: PWB for fetching articles and mwparserfromhell for parsing.